# python win32com excel >> ws.cells(1, 1).value does not work

Tags: python, excel, win32com

i have used win32com.client to to something with excel.

so far, ".cells(1, 1).value" method succesfully read the value in row1, column1.

but from now, that code doesn't work.
it occurs error >>
'<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library._Worksheet instance at 0x2284591006720>' object has no attribute 'cells'

what is a problem?

```
xlsApp = win32com.client.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")
wb = xlsApp.Workbooks(wb_name)
ws = wb.Worksheets(ws_name)

test = ws.cells(1, 1).value
print(test)
```

Comment: your `ws_name` variable hasn't been assigned a value (at least in the snippet you posted)

Answer (score 0):

The method name is `Cells()` with an uppercase ‘C’ is the simple answer.

It is fair to ask: “If `cells()` worked before, why doesn’t it work now?”. IMHO it is a failing of win32com.

win32com will, if asked, generate a wrapper for COM objects (using a package called `gen_py` which creates a Python file for each object). If such a wrapper exists win32com will use it by default. This wrapper is case-sensitive. This is “early binding”.

If there is not a wrapper then calls like `GetActiveObject()` and `Dispatch()` will use “late binding” where win32com will try and call whatever method you want on the object (whether the method exists or not). The package takes whatever method you ask for and tries to get the ID of that function from the COM object via `IDispatch.GetIdsOfNames()`. Crucially, this lookup is case-INsensitive: using `cells()`,`Cells()` or even `cElLs()` will all work.

And this is the problem. The generated wrappers are stored in the user’s directory. Your code might have been happily using late-binding and `cells()`, but another programme may have created the wrapper at a later date. Now your code will see this wrapper and switch to early-binding and now `cells()` no longer works: you need to use `Cells()`.

So, when using win32com it is always worth finding out the exact function name from the reference, eg [from here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.cells)